# How to convert HTML button to HTML input, while keeping all CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have a form with a textbox for email input and a button. The button is technically a HTML `button` here. The Form's HTML is like this:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

**JSFiddle Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/aDhUL/

I'd like to convert the `button type="submit"` control to an `input type="submit"`, while also keeping all the current CSS, so that visually there's no change. CSS would need to be updated I guess. I tried to do this myself, but I couldn't update the CSS correctly.

Can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: Next time, please tell us the exact CSS update that didn't work and how it didn't work (expected/actual behavior). See also: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: All `<input>`s should have a `<label>`. `placeholder` <> `<label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution requires changing the following everywhere  in your CSS

```
button -> input[type=button]
input -> input[type=text]
```

I'd prefer to add a CSS class, instead of referencing the tag names, you could just use

```
<input type="text" class="text" />
<input type="submit" class="btn" />
```

That would require changing the following everywhere in your CSS

```
button -> input.btn
input -> input.text
```

This is not fully finished but almost works http://jsfiddle.net/aDhUL/7/

The problem is that the `input:before` directive inserts an element inside of the input. That is allowed for `button`, but not allowed for `input` , since `input` can't have child elements. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

So (if you want to use :before) you have to go back to a button, inserting a span element between the text field and the button won't allow you to have a hover effect on both the arrow and the button.

Why do you want to use `input type="submit"` in the first place?

Comment: Looks good, but there's a small problem. If you look at my original code, you'll see a small triangle left sided arrow, on the left of the button, coming on top of the text box. This arrow goes away after applying your solution.

Comment: @Ahmad I'm not going to write your code for you! Please read my answer, it explains why you cannot do what you are trying to do with input, why do you want to use input in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I was just curious, that's all.  input type is more compliant with standards, and its more widely used, so I guess I wanted to try it out. However I've decided to go back to button for now. But still I'll mark your answer as the right one as you did help. Thanks !

Comment: @Ahmad I actually think `button` makes a lot more sense, a button doesn't really accept input, except for a click like any other HTML element. I 100% disagree that input type="button" is more compliant with standards, why do you think that? I thought you were trying to work around a bug

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `button` to `input[type=submit]` in your stylesheets. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to be more specific about what problems you're having.

Comment: It needs more than that, because there are CSS styles referencing input , which will now affect the button

Comment: @JuanMendes Good call. I didn't notice that was there - I generally don't see styling `input` without the type modifier, didn't think to look at that.

Comment: That's why I suggested using classes in my answer, it's less confusing

Comment: The left side arrow disappears after applying your suggested change. Its the small triangle shape directly on the left side of the button, hovering in front of the input text box.

Comment: @Ahmad See my answer, it explains why it's gone

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit CSS, don't be lazy mate :)

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="submit">
</form>
```

CSS

```
.btn{
color:green;
}
```

Now you can also use after adding the class in CSS

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the style sheets have to be updated to do so:

What is now this:

```
/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper button {
```

Needs to become this:

```
/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper input[type=submit] {
```

there are a bunch more classes to be updated below that one..

EDIT: changed it from a class to the style as joe points out.

Comment: It needs more than that, because there are CSS styles referencing `input` , which will now affect the button